# Set background color of an element when touch - android

Tags: android

Inside my `CustomAdapter` for a list, I want to change the background color of a row in my list when the user presses one of the rows.

I have a static class which contains the object in each row of the list:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView text;   
}
```

The holder contains the elements inside my list:

```
 holder = new ViewHolder();
 holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
 holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
 convertView.setTag(holder);

 holder.image.setImageResource(items.get(position).getImage());
 holder.text.setText(items.get(position).getTextToView());
```

To this convertView I added a `setOnTouchListener` this way:

```
 convertView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch(event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                //Toast.makeText(c, "DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //Toast.makeText(c, "UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }

    });
```

I tried this:

```
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

but my complier complaints, saying that the `convertView` should be `final` and that interfers with some other code.

This works perfectly to raise a `Toast` when the user presses a row in my list. 
But how can I change the background color of the row that is pressed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to update a value in your model then simple call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to just set the "final" modifier to an object that points to the convertView.

```
final View view = convertView;

holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
view.setTag(holder);

holder.image.setImageResource(items.get(position).getImage());
holder.text.setText(items.get(position).getTextToView());    

// And the listener
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch(event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
            //Toast.makeText(c, "DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //Toast.makeText(c, "UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for your problem - use temporary final variable.

Problem occurs because in some cases (maybe not on your) reference of convertView can be changed outside listener scope.

More Android-like solution - use state drawables if possible - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
 yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       ....
       view.setBackgroundColor(....);
       ....

     }
 });
```